Why do Gerundives ever exist when they can technically be rewritten with, "Necesse est (DO) (inf)...."
Libri legendi = The books are to be read.
Necesse est libris legi. = It is right/necessary for the books to be read.
Technically, these two sentences, although they are grammatically different, mean the same thing. Did the Romans want to have a different way to say the same thing or do these two sentences differ from each other in some significant way?

The Romans didn't invent Latin. You have redundancies in every language. Think about it: "I enjoy running" and "I like to run." Why do we have two different ways of saying this? Because we do. That's just how language works. There is no "why" about it.

("How it came to be", the other hand, can be answered and is a useful question.)

Not all gerundives can be rewritten in that way. The gerundive is used for other things besides the passive periphrastic.

@cmw Would you be willing to interpret "Why" charitably and answer "How it came to be"?

@BenKovitz I think the final question points towards looking at meaning and not historical development. It's not about charitable or uncharitable interpretations (I didn't downvote!), it's just a different kind of question, one that many people mistakenly ask when they first embark on learning a new language.

Why does the active voice exist when everything can be written using the passive voice by me? The gerundive and the active voice are shorter and I like them
